# Filter on a group on a content query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have a content query that I create in snippets, thats content query retrieve results from a list , I want to filter based on a column assigned to that contain a group of user, so i have to filter by the group of the current user , have you a custom value or query to do that 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the *Membership* element to do that:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
    <Eq>
       <FieldRef ID='AssignedTo' />
       <Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value>
    </Eq>
    <Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'>
       <FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />
    </Membership>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

Ref: http://www.martinhatch.com/2010/11/tip-caml-query-retrieve-tasks-assigned.html

The example above will return all items where the "AssignedTo" column (a multi-select "User or Group" field) contains either the current user directly, or a group of which the current user is a member.

Comment: yeah that work for a filtering a list, but what i want filter is a query content in the snippet of a master page which based in the list, the problem that this query is based on the list not a specific view

Comment: So if it is possible I want that my query content based on a list view not on a view